# How to find a value with a specific name in an array of object

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to find a value from an array of object obtained from an API request :

I'm using Vue2

I have a dataset like this :

```
content:[
    {
        name: title1,
        value: value1
    },
    {
         name: title2,
         value: value2
    },
...
]
```

I would like to get a value to use it in my template like this

```
<p>{{ value with the name title2 }}</p>
```

Do someone have any idea on how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can you the built-in [Array find prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```
<p>{{ content.find(e => e.name === 'title2').value }}</p>
```

**Edited** How to set the content value

You can declare content variable to store your API data in data section:

```
data() {
  return {
    content: []
  }
}
```

Call API and set value for the variable:

```
 created() {
    axios.get(url)
    .then(response => 
    { 
      this.content = response.data; 
    })
  }
```

Comment: Thank you ! And how do I get the value of this content ?

Comment: I have updated my answer. You can declare the content in data

Comment: So I can make something like this : <p>{{ content.find(e => e.name === 'title2').value }}</p>?

Comment: Yes, of course. But for now, your template looks a bit complicated because you add too much code to it. Let's declare a computed value and  use <p>{{ yourComputedValue }}</p>

Comment: So I need to make the filter on computed ?

Comment: Yes, you should put your filter in a computed, but it's optional. Just to make your template more isolated from the script

Comment: But this : <p>{{ content.find(e => e.name === 'title2').value }}</p> will be functionnal and complicated but still wordking ?

Comment: yes, it should work as soon as you have declared the content variable and set its value in the right way. Just notice that you can't use null safety in the template and your code may crash in runtime. You can do like this in script "content?.find(e => e.name === 'title2')?.value", but not inside template.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235252/discussion-between-antoine-kurka-and-quyt).

Answer (score 0):

You can use computed and just put it in template:

```js
computed: {
    title2 () {
       return this.content.filter(e => e.name === 'title2')
    }
}
```

ps: this will display your object in dom in a list.

If you just want the name you can do this:

```js
computed: {
    title2 () {
       const title = this.content.filter(e => e.name === 'title2')
       return title[0].name
    }
}
```

Comment: The main problem is that I will maybe need to get 100 values on 1 view so I need to do this 100 times

Comment: can you add more details to your question then ? Explain more so we can give better answers

Comment: I would like to make a simple content modifier. In my back office I have the title of the content like "header paragraph". And on my my main page view, I'm doing an API request to get all the content. I would like to display the value of the content where the title is "header paragraph". I don't know if this is clear.

Comment: I am not sure I understood this clearly but what I got: you can just modify filter like this  e => e.name === this.header-paragraph ?

Comment: If I'm trying to get the value of the content from the header. I would like to make something like this :  e => e.name === "header-parahraph" and get the value where the title is header-paraprah

Comment: yeah if i understood you correctly. give it a try and let us know maybe ?